# Java annoying iterator won't return an element in a linked-list

Tags: java, exception, iterator

Given the following code :

```
public void insertIntoQueue(float length,int xElement,int yElement,int whichElement)
    {
        Dot dot = new Dot(xElement,yElement);
        GeometricElement element = null;

        // some code 

        int robotX,robotY;
        boolean flag = false;
        for (Iterator<Robot> i = robotList.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
        {

            // Robot currentRobot = (Robot) i.next();           

             robotX = ((Robot)(i)).getXlocation();
             robotY = ((Robot)(i)).getYlocation();

        // more code , irrelevant 
    }
```

I have the following objects : Robot,GeometricElement and Dot .

I want to iterate on a Robot linked list which defined as:

```
public class Ground {

    // more fields 

    private LinkedList <Robot> robotList;  // used for storing the robots 
    public Ground(int row,int col)   // ctor 
{
            // some code 

    this.robotList = new LinkedList<Robot>();
}
}
```

but the line : `robotX = ((Robot)(i)).getXlocation();` 
and robotY = `((Robot)(i)).getYlocation();` 
throws an exception of `dispatchUncaughtException` .

Please pay attention that I don't want to remove elements from the linked list,
what I need is to get fields from a current element with the iterator.

So what's wrong ?

Regards
Ron

Comment: Looks like you're casting i to be a Robot when it's actually of type Iterator<Robot>...Perhaps you want to cast i.next() instead?

Comment: When I do that with i.next() , "i" proceeds to the following element, and doesn't return the current , meaning "i" doesn't stay on the current element , it moves to the next one

Comment: So maybe you want to create a temporary Robot that is equal to i.next(), so that you can use it twice.

Comment: I did just that , but , any changes that I'd do to the temporary Robot wouldn't change the linkedlist ...

Comment: What if you just said Robot temp = i.next() That should reference that actual variable, no?

Comment: `dispatchUncaughtException` is a method not an exception.  What is the actual exception?

Comment: @ron fyi, see my edit to my answer for how I would code it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your commented out line is actually the *correct* line, except remove the cast:

```
Robot currentRobot = i.next();
```

Because your iterator is typed, you dont need the cast and the compiler ensures you're working with the right kind of object.

After that, you can simply:

```
robotX = currentRobot.getXlocation();
robotY = currentRobot.getYlocation();
```

No ugly casts!

BTW, if you don't need to modify the collection via the iterator, you can improve the code style considerably, buy using a "foreach":

```
for (Robot currentRobot : robotList) {
    robotX = currentRobot.getXlocation();
    robotY = currentRobot.getYlocation();
    // .. more code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast the iterator to a Robot object. That's never going to work, it's not a Robot, it's an iterator.

```
Robot robot = (Robot)iterator.next();
robotX = robot.getXlocation();
```

Comment: I'm assuming you typed that in Dr. McCoy's voice.

Comment: lol [I'm a doctor, not a bricklayer!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonard_McCoy#.22I.27m_a_doctor.2C_not_a.28n.29....22)